# Python global variable not working in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, global-variables

I'm passing kwargs from a function to another function and declare the variable as global to use it in query but not working.

```
def do_stuff_then_call_taxman(**kwargs):
    employee_id = kwargs['employee_id']

    ''' doing stuff'''

    taxman(employee_id=employee_id)

def taxman(**kwargs):

    global employee_id #<--- ATTENTION HERE 
    employee_id = kwargs['employee_id']



qs = Employee.objects.filter(id=employee_id).values() #Error occurs here

 NameError at /timesheet/ name 'employee_id' is not defined


for global_variable in qs:

    '''variables'''
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just define `employee_id`,but it does not exist in the **runtime**

---

add something like `do_stuff_then_call_taxman(employee_id=1)`before`qs = Employee.objects.filter(id=employee_id).values()`